# How to update a datastore ListProperty entity adding new elements (without replacing the olds)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, list, datastore

I have this class:

```
class Contract(db.Model):
    book_number = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    initial_page = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    final_page = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    contract_type = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    parties = db.ListProperty(int)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty (required = True, auto_now = True, auto_now_add = True)

class ContractingParty(db.Model):
    person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person, required=True, collection_name="party_to_contracts")
    contract = db.ReferenceProperty(Contract, required=True)
    condition = db.StringProperty()
```

I use this code to create an entity named `Contract` which `parties` property is an empty list:

```
    parties = []
    contract_record = Contract(book_number = int(numBook),
                               initial_page = int(numInitialPage),
                               final_page = int(numFinalPage),
                               contract_type = choosed_contract_type,
                               parties = parties)
    contract_record.put()
```

But I have to populate the `parties` property with IDs of ContractingPerson entitty. So, in other part of the code, I uptade the `parties` property of `Contract` entity, this way:

```
contracting_party_record = ContractingParty(person = person_key,
                                                      contract = contract_key,
                                                      condition = get_condition)
contracting_party_record.put()
contracting_party_id = contracting_party_record.key().id()
contract = Contract.get_by_id(contract_id)
contract.parties.append(contracting_party_id)
#contract.parties.extend(contracting_party_id)
contract.put()
```

But when I query datastore, this way:

```
parties = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ContractingParty WHERE contract =:c_key", c_key = contract_key).fetch(20)
```

I got only the last ContractingParty entity I've create. It seems that `contract.parties.append(contracting_party_id)` is replacing the old list with the new one. Then, I tried to use `contract.parties.extend(contracting_party_id)`. But, now, I got this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Py\Desktop\contract\main.py", line 363, in post
    contract.parties.extend(contracting_party_id)
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

appending items on the list like contract.parties.append(contracting_party_id) does not replace the previous list it shouldn't do it in your case too.

what you want to do is using `append` instead of `extend`.

while `extend` expects an iterable like another list, `append` adds an item to the list.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l.append(4)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4] 

>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l.extend([4,5,6])
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

here the docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thanks, aschmid00, the error was in other place of my code. Your answer help find it.

Comment: Thanks either for explaining the extend list method.